# $a^3+b^3+2(a^2+b^2)=b^3+c^3+2(b^2+c^2)=c^3+a^3+2(c^2+a^2), a\not=b\not=c$; what is $ab+bc+ca$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $a^3+b^3+2(a^2+b^2)=b^3+c^3+2(b^2+c^2)=c^3+a^3+2(c^2+a^2) \\ a\not=b\not=c \\ ab+bc+ca=$

since $a^3+b^3+2(a^2+b^2)=b^3+c^3+2(b^2+c^2)$

$a^3+c^3=-2(a+c)(a-c)=(a-c)(a^2-ac+c^2)$

$-2a-2c=a^2-ac+c^2$

$a^2+c^2+2a+2c=ac$

isw, $ab+bc+ca=2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+4(a+b+c)$

Comment: there is a mistake in the line "since ..". It should be $a^3 - c^3$ and it is equal to $(a-c)(a^2 + ac + c^2)$

Answer (score 1):

Bigbang pointed out a typo. It's not immediately clear to me how the solution can be continued from there.

---

**Hint:** Show that $ a, b, c$ are the distinct roots of $ x^3 + 2x^2 + k  = 0 $ for some $k$.

Hence, conclude that $ ab+bc+ca = 0 $.

Comment: Oh.. When $a^3+b^3+2(a^2+b^2)=b^3+c^3+2(b^2+c^2)=c^3+a^3+2(c^2+a^2)=k$, $2(a^3+ b^3+c^3)+4(a^2+b^2+c^2)=2k$, $(a^3+ b^3+c^3)+2(a^2+b^2+c^2)=k$. but I'm not sure that $a^3+2a^2=k$ and $b^3+2b^2=k$ and $c^3+2c^2=k$.

Comment: @Phoenixrafaelthemusicmake You have the idea. Some of your $k$'s are different, so you should keep proper track of that instead of the abuse of notation that you're using (which likely makes you not sure of the rest). Show that $ a^3 + a^2 = (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 2 ( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ) - [ b^3 + c^3 + 2 ( b^2 + c^2) ] = k_1 - k_2 = K.$

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a typo mistake. It should be $a^3-c^3$

> Then factorise the LHS and obtain $(a-c)(a^2+ac+c^2)$ and try to move on from there

Comment: To check, are you able to move on from there?